# Securing Windows Phone 7 App?

Tags: .net, security, windows-phone-7, cracking

I'm about to port some of my applications to Windows Phone 7. At the moment, these apps are all native, C++ or Delphi. Over the years I've developed a good understanding and skills on how to secure the native code against cracking, keygening, etc. But, i'm completely unaware on how to protect .NET code.

What are the best practices in the .NET world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you can't use C++ code for Windows Phone development so you will need to rewrite your code.

At most you can have your code obfuscated and will have to allow Microsoft to take care of handling the hackers anytime a new exploit is found.

Comment: Here is the link a free obfuscator for Windows Phone 7, they have some type of an arrangement with Microsoft to provide this to us I believe. http://www.preemptive.com/windowsphone7.html